# TypeInitializationException while getting fingerprint scanner list in Windows 8 Metro App using Neuro technology SDK

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, biometrics

I am using [trial VeriFinger SDK](http://neurotechnology.com). I have added all the supported DLLs from dotNET_Portable folder. I have changed AnyCPU to x64. But I am getting exeption while initializing NDeviceManager object. My code is given below. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for
>   "Neurotec.Devices.NDeviceManager" threw an exception. Exception
>   message : The type initializer for "Neurotec.Devices.NDeviceManager"
>   threw an exception. InnerException : Unable to load DLL "NDevices":
>   The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E)

```
using Neurotec.Devices;

private NDeviceManager _deviceMan;

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _deviceMan = new NDeviceManager(NDeviceType.FingerScanner, true);
}

private void btnRefreshScannerList_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var Scanners = _deviceMan.Devices;
    //TODO:
}
```

Comment: **WinRT**? It seems it's a **not supported environment** (see [this page](http://neurotechnology.com/verifinger-system-requirements.html)).

Comment: I asked their support team they told me the trial SDK has "dotNET_Portable" folder which contains DLLs supported to x86 & x64 WinRT not ARM WinRT.

Comment: Based on [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/14dc569b-b761-4021-b3a7-559138daaf71/the-specified-module-could-not-be-found), you may be missing the driver DLL as a reference, either in your PCL or WinRT project. It further suggests you check out [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to try and track down which DLL it is.

Comment: No, I don't think I am missing any module. As I am following it's Winform app. I added all the DLLs same (name wise only) as WinForm app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to dotNET_Portable dlls, you also need to add native libraries NDevices.dll, NCore.dll, NMedia.dll & other dependencies from Bin\Win64_x64 (or Bin\Win32_x86, depending on what platform you are targeting). Please refer to picture how this should be done:

[image: adding native binaries to project]

Comment: Where do I need to copy ? When I try to add reference of those DLLs, I am getting error that "it's not valid assembly or COM components". Do I need to use DLLs from "dotNET_Portable" or from "Bin\Win64_x64 or Bin\Win32_x86". I am creating Windows 8 metro app, not the WinForm or WPF app.

Comment: You need to use both DLLs from dotNET_Portable (which you're probably using correctly, as they are like any other .NET assembly), and also native DLLs, which should be added as content to project (see edited answer for screenshot how this is done in Visual Studio).